# Inspect Java bytecode using Bytecode Frameworks (Android)

Tags: java, android, bytecode, byte-buddy

I am trying to achieve the following:

- Inspect a Java method's byte codes for tampering or manipulation.

I came across the term bytecode framework and online searches led me to ASM, Byte Buddy etc. I tried to get a ClassReader object of `java.lang.Object` and I got a ClassNotFound exception in Android.

```
        try {
            ClassReader classreader = new ClassReader("java.lang.Object");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

For various testing, I have included the following in my build.gradle file

```
    implementation("net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-android:1.14.12")

    implementation("org.ow2.asm:asm:9.4")
    implementation("org.ow2.asm:asm-util:9.2")
```

For now, I want to be able to list or print the opcodes of the methods in a class.

Has anyone gotten this to work in Android? Any help is appreciated.

References

- https://www.baeldung.com/java-class-view-bytecode

Comment: Android is not Java. It's running Dalvik bytercode on a Dalvik runtime/VM. While you program it in Java, the final "binary" on-device does not contain any Java bytecode, so any library that tries to read that will not find what it's looking for.

Comment: The underlying operation which must be supported by the environment is `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("java/lang/Object.class")`

Comment: This looks to be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You should provide more clarity into what are you trying to achieve, what is the original problem you are trying to resolve.

Comment: Hi @aled

Let me clarify. I am trying to detect inline hooking in Java methods by inspecting the opcodes in a java method to see perhaps if there was some branching instruction etc. I am not sure if this is possible so I need to find out.